# CSS Footer grid responsive

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, footer

I am trying to make a 5 column grid layout on my footer responsive depending on the size of the client screen.

If the screen is larger than width x, then the columns are next to each other. If the screen is smaller than width x, then the first 4 columns are grouped into 2, so that 2 rows are created, while the 5th column maintains its width.

In addition, The 5th column has fixed width of 438px, while the first two columns have width depending on the size of the screen, so filing the remaining width of the window. Below I am illustrating my result I am desiring:

[image: Width greater than x]

[image: Width less than x]

Below, I am listing my CSS and HTML:

```css
.cont-links{
  padding: 20px;
}

.links{
  background-color: #1481BA;
}

.links .links-wrapper{
  display: table-row-group;
}

.links .footer-nav-wrapper{
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

// .links .footer-nav-wrapper .first-two-wrap, .links .footer-nav-wrapper .last-two-wrap{
//   display: table-cell;
// }

.links .footer-nav-wrapper .link-group{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.links span{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.links .footer-nav-wrapper .link-group > .footer-link-wrapper{
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.links span:first-child{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #63CCCA;
}

.links a{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.links .title{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.links .connect{
  width: 418px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.links .connect span{
  display: block;
}

.links .connect .logo{
  height: 80px;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.links .connect .title-follow-us-wrapper{
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.links .connect .footer-social-icons-wrapper img{
  height: 71px;
  width: 71px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section class="links">
    <div class="cont cont-links">
      <div class="links-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-nav-wrapper">

            <div class="link-group about">
              <span><a href="about/index.php" class="title">About</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="about/whatistechpocket/index.php" class="link-1">What is TechPocket?</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="about/whoarewe/index.php" class="link-2">Who Are We</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="about/team/index.php" class="link-3">Meet The Team</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="link-group community">
              <span><a href="#" class="title">community</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="blog/index.php" class="link-1">Blog</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="forum/index.php" class="link-2">Forum</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="youtubevideos/index.php" class="link-3">TechPocket</a></span>
            </div>

            <div class="link-group support">
              <span><a href="support/index.php" class="title">Support</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="donate/index.php" class="link-1">Donate</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="report/index.php" class="link-2">Report An Issue</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="link-group contact-us">
              <span><a href="contactus/index.php" class="title">Contact Us</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="contactus/index.php" class="link-1">Leave A Message</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="privacy/index.php" class="link-2">Privacy Policy</a></span>
              <span class="footer-link-wrapper"><a href="terms/index.php" class="link-3">Terms Of Service</a></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="connect">
          <span><a href="#" class="title">Connect With Us</a></span>
          <div class="logo"></div>
          <div class="brief-page-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nullam dictum semper lorem sed sollicitudin. Nunc eleifend
suscipit erat, fringilla ornare justo pretium nec. Proin sit
amet massa nec massa pellentesque rutrum non sit amet arcu.</div>
          <span class="title-follow-us-wrapper"><a href="#" class="title title-follow-us">Follow Us:</a></span>
          <div class="footer-social-icons-wrapper">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/techpocketofficial" target="_blank"><img src="views/css/facebook-logo.png" alt="FB" class="fb-logo"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/techpocket1" target="_blank"><img src="views/css/twitter-logo.png" alt="Twitter" class="twitter-logo"></a>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/+techpocketvideo" target="_blank"><img src="views/css/google-icon.png" alt="Google+" class="google-logo"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="social"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

I have tried multiple methods to get this to work and the response couldn't come to light. I would either achieve either of the two layouts. My question is: Is there a way where I could make the first 4 columns responsive as shown above and leave the last column fixed to the right without using any JS?

I will much appreciate your help.

Comment: "I am trying to make a 5 column grid layout" - Have you looked at using CSS Grid? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: grid is supported on newer browsers. I also want it to work on the older browsers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `display:flex;` property to fix the .connect width, and make the other with part width adapting itself.

Moreover, use can use the media queries to change the width of something, depending on the width of the user window.

Here is your code: https://jsfiddle.net/ou6n9xs0/42/